# React Router v6 - Create Invalid Path Redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to make it so if the user enters an invalid path in the URL it automatically redirects them to the homepage.

Something like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />}/>
        <Route exact path="/page" element={<page />}/>
        <Route path="*" /*Go to path - "/" */ />
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Render a redirect as the routed component, in this case the `Navigate` component with the `replace` prop specified.

```
<Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
```

Comment: It does work without replace with react-router-dom 6+. Did not throw any error.

Comment: @Anil_M Sure, you can omit the `replace` prop and issue a PUSH navigation by default. Note that this is a "forward" navigation and a new entry will be PUSH-ed onto the history stack, as opposed to redirecting by REPLACE-ing the current entry in the history stack.